# How do I correctly rotate an image with asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, image-processing

I want to rotate an image with asp.net. I used TranslateTransform and RotateTransform. After rotation, the image is damaged. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that shows how to do it correctly using System.Drawing:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1234460/2239261.aspx

Relevant code from the [post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1234460/2239261.aspx):

```
public Bitmap RotateBitmap(float Angle, Bitmap bm_in)
{
    try
    {
        float wid = bm_in.Width;
        float hgt = bm_in.Height;
        Point[] corners = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(int.Parse(wid.ToString()), 0), new Point(0, int.Parse(hgt.ToString())), new Point(int.Parse(wid.ToString()), int.Parse(hgt.ToString())) };
        int cx = int.Parse(wid.ToString()) / 2;
        int cy = int.Parse(hgt.ToString()) / 2;
        long i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            corners[i].X -= Convert.ToInt32(cx.ToString());
            corners[i].Y -= Convert.ToInt32(cy.ToString());
        }

        float theta = (float)(Angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
        float sin_theta = (float)Math.Sin(theta);
        float cos_theta = (float)Math.Cos(theta);
        float X;
        float Y;
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            X = corners[i].X;
            Y = corners[i].Y;
            corners[i].X = (int)(X * cos_theta + Y * sin_theta);
            corners[i].Y = (int)(-X * sin_theta + Y * cos_theta);
        }

        float xmin = corners[0].X;
        float ymin = corners[0].Y;
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            if (xmin > corners[i].X)
                xmin = corners[i].X;
            if (ymin > corners[i].Y)
                ymin = corners[i].Y;
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            corners[i].X -= int.Parse(xmin.ToString());
            corners[i].Y -= int.Parse(ymin.ToString());
        }

        Bitmap bm_out = new Bitmap((int)(-2 * xmin), (int)(-2 * ymin));
        Graphics gr_out = Graphics.FromImage(bm_out);
        // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement
        Point[] temp = new Point[3];
        if (corners != null)
        {
            Array.Copy(corners, temp, Math.Min(corners.Length, temp.Length));
        }
        corners = temp;
        gr_out.DrawImage(bm_in, corners);
        return bm_out;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        return bm_in;
    }
}
```

Comment: Converting `float` to `int` through `string`? And then “converting” `int` to `int` using the same method? That's not a good idea.